# Look for specified values in a field, but dont show any records where the last record in that field is '1100'

Tags: sql, oracle, filter

What I am trying to do is find all records where the enquiry may at some point in it's life had a status code of "EN13" or "EN93" - however, the bit where I am struggling is that I need to omit all records from the report where the final status code on the enquiry is "1100" - even if "EN13" or "EN93" are present in the history of that enquiry.

The code I've got so far is

```
select
central_enquiry.enquiry_number,
central_enquiry.enquiry_time,
central_enquiry.service_code,
enquiry_status_log.enq_status_code,
central_enquiry.enquiry_desc,
central_enquiry.outstanding_flag

from
central_enquiry
inner join enquiry_status_log on central_enquiry.enquiry_number = 
enquiry_status_log.enquiry_number

where
central_enquiry.service_code = 'GABV' and
enquiry_status_log.enq_status_code in ('EN13', 'EN93') and

((central_enquiry.enquiry_time > ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-1) AND
central_enquiry.enquiry_time < SYSDATE)) 

order by 
central_enquiry.enquiry_number
```

Comment: Your question mentions "job"s but nothing in the query is called "job".

Comment: Apologies - have mixed up the "job" and "enquiry" words.  This is definitely enquiries I'm interested in and have edited the post to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LAST_VALUE or FIRST_VALUE to get the latest status:

```
select *
from
 (
    select
    central_enquiry.enquiry_number,
    central_enquiry.enquiry_time,
    central_enquiry.service_code,
    enquiry_status_log.enq_status_code,
    central_enquiry.enquiry_desc,
    central_enquiry.outstanding_flag,

    -- latest status per enquiry_number
    first_value(enquiry_status_log.enq_status_code)
    over (partition by enquiry_status_log.enquiry_number
          order by central_enquiry.enquiry_time desc) as last_status

    from
    central_enquiry
    inner join enquiry_status_log on central_enquiry.enquiry_number = 
    enquiry_status_log.enquiry_number

    where
    central_enquiry.service_code = 'GABV' and

    ((central_enquiry.enquiry_time > ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-1) AND
    central_enquiry.enquiry_time < SYSDATE)) 
 ) dt
where enq_status_code in ('EN13', 'EN93')
  and last_status <> '1100'
order by enquiry_number
```

Comment: Thanks - this is coming back with an error message saying ENQUIRY_STATUS_LOG.ENQ_STATUS_CODE invalid identifier.

Comment: Of course, removed the table name from the outer WHERE

Comment: Thank you.  My version of Oracle SQL didn't allow the * to be used with Select * at the beginning of the statement but have pulled the values through using the "dt" table referenced in the sub-query.

Answer (score 0):

As my version of Oracle SQL didn't allow for Select * to be used below is the code that was used to get it working.

Thanks to Dnoeth.

```
select
dt.enquiry_number,
dt.enquiry_time,
dt.service_code,
dt.enq_status_code,
dt.enquiry_desc,
dt.outstanding_flag,

-- latest status per enquiry_number
first_value(dt.enq_status_code)
over (partition by dt.enquiry_number
      order by dt.enquiry_time desc) as last_status

from
(
select
central_enquiry.enquiry_number,
central_enquiry.enquiry_time,
central_enquiry.service_code,
enquiry_status_log.enq_status_code,
central_enquiry.enquiry_desc,
central_enquiry.outstanding_flag,

-- latest status per enquiry_number
first_value(enquiry_status_log.enq_status_code)
over (partition by enquiry_status_log.enquiry_number
      order by central_enquiry.enquiry_time desc) as last_status

from
central_enquiry
inner join enquiry_status_log on central_enquiry.enquiry_number = 
enquiry_status_log.enquiry_number

where
central_enquiry.service_code = 'GABV' and

((central_enquiry.enquiry_time > ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-1) AND
central_enquiry.enquiry_time < SYSDATE)) 
) dt

where enq_status_code in ('EN13', 'EN93')
and last_status <> '1100'
order by enquiry_number
```